# Bash - Script error if folder with spaces

Tags: bash, logging, directory, space, names

I have this script

```
#!/bin/bash

rename_files() {
   title="${1##*${2} - }"
   for filename in "$1/"*.*; do
   case "${filename##*.}" in
     doc|doc|doc)
       mkdir -p -m 777 "/Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/${title}"
       new_path="/Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/${title}/${title}.${filename##*.}"
       let "iters=1"
       while [ -f $new_path ] ; do
          new_path=$new_path"$iters"
          let "iters++"
       done
       echo "moving $filename -> $new_path"
       mv "${filename}" "${new_path}"
       ;;
   esac
   done
}

rename_category() {
  for path in "/Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloads/${1}"*; do
    rename_files "$path" "$1"
  done
}

rename_category DOC
```

This script automatically moves and renames files contained in `/Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded`. All is working fine if I use a folder called `Documents` instead of `Documents Share`. I tried to do use `Documents\ Share` but it doesn't work.

Here is the error log

```
/Users/Desktop/Script.sh: line 11: [: /Users/Desktop/Documents: binary operator expected
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: `case "${filename##*.}"  in doc|doc|doc )` ?? wth?  Good luck.

Comment: Only an extension example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the variables *everywhere*. Double quotes are missing in the indicated line:

```
while [ -f $new_path ] ; do
```

shoudl be

```
while [ -f "$new_path" ] ; do
```

Answer (score 1):

I think $new_path (line 11) should be enclosed by double quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me but choroba answered a few minutes before you; I'm really sorry I can't flag as best answer more than one answer.

Comment: Yes I know. Don't worry, I'm glad to have been useful.
Maybe next time